# Replace try { } catch { } block for file upload

Tags: c#, try-catch, openfiledialog

I have a file upload using an `OpenFileDialog()`, so I can read .csv files and add the to a datagrid. However, if the `OpenFileDialog` is closed without a file selected, it crashes. so I placed it in a `try { } catch { }` block as a temporary fix.

Can someone provide a better solution to a file not being selected?

**EDIT**
Here is my OpenFileDialog Code:

```
// ... Code to Setup OFD here ...

// If the search for the file is OK (i.e. the file exists), stores the filename in a string.
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
// Runs the Populate Data Grid View method.
UploadFromExternalSource();
```

Here is the AddtoDataGrid code:

```
// Try/catch used if a file was not uploaded.
try
{
    // Reads the text and splits the text into rows by each new line.
    importFile = File.ReadAllText(CView.fileName).Split('\n');
    foreach (string line in importFile)
    {
        // Splits each line into indiviual columns each time it comes in contact with a comma (",")
        // then increments the line count (determined by the new line) by 1.
        data = line.Split(',');
        CView.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data);
        lineCount++;
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()` will return `DialogResult`. You can check for `DialogResult.OK` if the user selected the file.

Example:

```
var opf = new OpenFileDialog();

if(opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: on top of that, you can use the member "CheckFileExists" to assist in ensuring your file does, indeed, exist. ref: MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.checkfileexists(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I do have the `if()`. Edited question to add that, unfortunately I still need the `try/catch`

Comment: yes. you need to handle `FileNotFoundException` and `IOExcaption`; handling IO exceptions are necessary. can you tell what exception it is throwing?

Comment: Quite simply: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path`

Comment: Its a `NullPointerException`. You shouldn't handle `NullPointerException` but check the variable for `null` before using it. Seeing that you're calling the `File.ReadAllText(CView.fileName)`, `CView.fileName` must be `null`. Put a breakpoint on this line check the `CView.fileName` value.

Comment: @karti so `if (filename != null) { // upload to DG }` ?

Comment: yes. and also you can include `File.Exists(fileName)` in the if statement, like this: `if(fileName != null && File.Exists(fileName)) { //upload }` will ensure the file is present 90% and still, while reading the file, you should handle `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException`(if you're reopening). Because, while the program is in CPU wait(context switch) after the if statement and meanwhile the file is deleted or the media is not present will throw the above exceptions.